# AngularJS + IE 11 + Polymer = ng-model not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, polymer, internet-explorer-11

In a directive in my application I have a text input with a variable bound using ng-model:

```
<input type="text" class="text-input" ng-change="onInputChange()" ng-model="value" />
```

I've set up the following in my link function:

```
scope.onInputChange = function() {
   console.log(scope.value);
};

scope.$watch('value', function(value) {
   console.log(value);
});

setInterval(function(){
   console.log(scope.value);
}, 500);
```

As I type in the input field, the ng-change and watch are never fired and the interval always outputs undefined.

Running this directive in a standalone application in IE 11 works.

Running this directive in a standalone application in Chrome (latest) works.

Running my whole application in Chrome (latest) works.

What in my application could be causing this behaviour?

**Edit 2:**

This situation appears to have been caused by `webcomponents.js`. When this file is included in IE 11, it removes all event listeners from the DOM elements an replaces them with it's own `dispatchOriginalEvent` function. On the input field specified, it fails to replace any of the normal event listeners and so any text input is not noticed.

**Edit 3:**

I've narrowed down the problem further to the combination of Angular's ng-include and webcomponents.js polyfill for ShadowDOM. I have therefore added an issue to the [github](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/532) instance for webcomponentsjs

**EDIT: Full directive**

```
'use strict';

(function(angular) {

    angular.module('givemeareason', [
        'config'
    ]);

    angular.module('givemeareason')
        .directive('giveMeAReason', ['$timeout', 'AppConfig', function($timeout, Appconfig) {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                replace : true,
                template: '<div class="give-me-a-reason">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="reason" ng-change="onInputChange()" ng-model="reason" />' +
                    '</div>',
                require : 'ngModel',
                scope   : {
                    onChange: '&'
                },
                link    : function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelContoller) {
                    scope.onInputChange = function() {
                        scope.onChange({
                            item: {reason: scope.reason},
                            valid: typeof scope.reason === 'string' && scope.reason.length > 0
                        });
                    };

                    scope.$watch('reason', function(reason) {
                        console.log(reason);
                    });

                    setInterval(function(){
                        console.log(scope.reason);
                    }, 500);
                }
            };
        }]);
    }(window.angular));
```

Usage:

```
<give-me-a-reason id="paste-reason" ng-model="importVm.reasonModel" on-change="importVm.reasonChanged(item, valid)"></give-me-a-reason>
```

**EDIT:**

The following errors appear in the console. They may or may not be related:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'animate'. File: web-animations.min.js, Line 16, Column: 11207
Assertion failed. File: webcomponents.js, Line: 116, Column: 15
```

After exploring the over issues, they appear to be related to browsersync and the issue described in this question still occurs without them.

Comment: As a preliminary test try `ng-model="$parent.value"`. If it doesn't change please show us the code of your directive and a usage of it.

Comment: It didn't change. I've added the full code of the directive

Comment: 2 things, i would avoid using `on-change`. It's possible that its clashes for IE, try to rename it to something like `model-change`. Second if you want to bind your function do `on-change="importVm.reasonChanged"`. And then call `scope.onChange({reason:scope.reason}, typeof scope.reason==[....])`;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've applied both changes but still nothing. I have a feeling it's something else in my application which is causing this as a side-effect, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: I just remembered, i had once a probem with angular animate, i didn't really solve it : i added this in my link function : `$animate.enabled(false, element);` in order to disable $animate. Don't forget to add $animate to the $inject or inline-injection of course

Comment: I tried that, and then after some exploration have found it wasn't linked (see update)

Answer (score 0):

pass the value in your function

```
<input type="text" class="text-input" ng-change="onInputChange(value)" ng-model="value" />
```

Comment: `ng-change="onInputChange(value)"` instead of `ng-change="onInputChange()"`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ng-change` from your `input` and modify your directive code like this:

```
scope.onInputChange = function() {
    scope.onChange({
        item: {reason: scope.reason},
        valid: typeof scope.reason === 'string' && scope.reason.length > 0
    });
};

scope.$watch('reason', scope.onInputChange);
```

This is working fine for me. See an working example below:

```js
angular.module('givemeareason', []);

angular.module('givemeareason')
  .controller("foocontroller", function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.reasonChanged = function(item, valid) {
      console.log("In the controller", item, valid);
    }
  });

angular.module('givemeareason')
  .directive('giveMeAReason', ['$timeout',
    function($timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="give-me-a-reason">' +
          '<input type="text" class="reason" ng-model="reason" />' +
          '</div>',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          onChange: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelContoller) {
          scope.onInputChange = function() {
            console.log("Changed value", scope.reason);

            scope.onChange({
              item: {
                reason: scope.reason
              },
              valid: typeof scope.reason === 'string' && scope.reason.length > 0
            });
          };

          scope.$watch('reason', scope.onInputChange);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="givemeareason" ng-controller="foocontroller as importVm">
  <give-me-a-reason id="paste-reason" ng-model="importVm.reasonModel" on-change="importVm.reasonChanged(item, valid)"></give-me-a-reason>
</div>
```

Comment: The $watch function is not being fired, so this doesn't cause any changes

Comment: Oh let me try. Can you provide a plunkr or Stackoverflow snippet?

Comment: This is the problem. The directive by itself works fine.. But doesn't work within my wider application. I'm trying to find out what could be causing this.

Comment: You can debug by removing unused scripts piece by piece and then trying the application. Mean while, I'll attach the controller implementation as well.

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine. There is something else.